# Go wait for goroutines but do stuff in the meantime

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

i have the following go-Code:

```
func execTask(input int, results chan<- int) {
    //do stuff (in my case, start process and return something)
    results <- someResult
}

func main() {
    results := make(chan int)

    for _, task := range tasks {
        go execTask(task, results)
    }

    for result := range results {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

For the line `for result := range results {` I get an Error:
`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`. In the routine `execTask` I actually execute a process with os/exec, so I do not know how many results there are in `results`. So I have to wait for completion of all my processes, but in the meantime do something with the results. When all processes are terminated, my go-Programm may be terminated too.

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Lars

Comment: results := make(chan int)

    for _, task := range tasks {
        go execTask(task, results)
    }
Task is also calling results, that can cause deadlock..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the deadlock error because you are not closing `results` channel. Hence, `main` keeps on waiting for more data on `results` even after all the `execTask`'s have completed, and there is nothing else writing to `results`.

You can fix this by using `sync.WaitGroup`:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    results := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(len(tasks))
    for _, task := range tasks {
        go func(task int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            execTask(task, results)
        }(task)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait() // wait for each execTask to return
        close(results) // then close the results channel
    }

    for result := range results {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

As for working on `execTask` results while other processes are still executing, you already have the right idea. Just work on them in the `results` range loop. Kick off some more goroutines in there if you want more concurrent executions.

Comment: Don't use `task` from the range in your closure like that. Make your closure accept `task int` and pass it in: see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables